# SOSL syntax - Is first list element a single record?

Tags: sosl

```
List <Lead> results ;
String searchText;

public PageReference doSearch (){
results = (List<lead>) [Find :searchText RETURNING Lead (Name, email)] [0];
```

In the line of `results`, when I set *only* the first row (as in `[0]`) of list, does that mean a single lead record from the SOSL?

If so, would this have worked if results was defined as a single record instead of a list varible? That is:

```
Lead results;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do a SOSL search, it returns a `List<List<SObject>>`. If you're trying to get results for exactly one object type (`Lead`, for example), you might just want the one `List<SObject>` Since you're only `RETURNING` that type, you can just get the first element. A more verbose declaration would be:

```
List<List<SObject>> searchResults = [/*search*/];
List<Lead> leadResults = searchResults[0];
```